# Calling value from Lua table via variable

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have the following Lua table with information on a fixture that I'm trying to recall using a separate function.

This is the table:

```
Fixture = {
        Beam = {
            loaded_color = "Image 101",
            live_color = "Image 117",
            Colors = {
                White = "98.101",
                Red = "98.102",
                Orange = "98.103",
                Yellow = "98.104",
                FernGreen = "98.105",
                Green = "98.106",
                SeaGreen = "98.107",
                Cyan = "98.108",
                Lavender = "98.109",
                Blue = "98.110",
                Violet = "98.111",
                Magenta = "98.112",
                Pink = "98.113",
                CTO = "98.114",
                CTB = "98.115"
            }
        }
}
```

This is my function:

```
function color(type, color)
    color_load=gma.user.getvar('COLOR_LOAD')
    if color_load=='True' then
            var("LOADED_BEAM_COLOR", Fixture.type.Colors.color)
            cmd("Copy Image 84 At " .. Show.loaded_color_empty .. " /o")
            cmd("Copy " .. Show.Colors.color .. " At " .. Fixture.Beam.loaded_color)
    end
end
```

And this is how I'm calling the function:
`color('Beam', 'White')`

I know the function can see the variable passed to it but I keep getting the error that the variable `type` and `color` are both nill, even if when they are printed from the same function they have a value. Any ideas on what is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `Fixture.type.Colors.color` with `Fixture[type].Colors[color]`

You cannot use the dot syntax to index tables with variables.

Also you're not calling a value from a table here. You're attempting to  index a table here.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be something to do with the dots but couldn't figure out what. Also thanks for the clarification on the terminology!